# Angular template is adding up the data instead of updating it

Tags: angular

on service calls, data is being added up to the template instead of updating it. I used `changeDetectRef` too

For example:-
On new zip,drugCostService is being called , when I change the zip code, i get new data, that new data is being added up to the existing data. For zipcode:-12345, data is aaaaaaaaaaaaa.

For another zip code:- 78901, data is bbbbbbbb.
 Instead of showing bbbbbbb its showing aaaaaaa and bbbbbbb on template side

```
 constructor(
    private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

    this.drugCostService.drugPlan(this.zipCode, this.fipsCode).subscribe((response) => {

              this.ref.markForCheck();
              this.drugCostTable = response;
        }}
```

i tried   `this.ref.detectChanges();` but its doing same

HTML code

```
<table id="drugCost">
  <tr>
    <th id="monthHeader"> </th>
    <th>Drug Name</th>
    <th>Phase</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let element of dataSource">
    <td> {{element.month}} </td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of element">
          <td>{{item.LabelName}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of element">
          <td>{{item.Phase}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>

    <td>
      <table>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of element">
          <td>{{item.MemberCost}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: can you explain little more

Comment: On new zip,drugCostService  is being called , when I change the zip code, i get new data, that new data is being added up to the existing data.
For zipcode:-12345, data is aaaaaaaaaaaaa. For another zip code:- 78901, data is bbbbbbbb.
Instead of showing bbbbbbb its showing

aaaaaaa and bbbbbbb on template side

Comment: You shouldn't need any ```changeDetectRef```. Let's see your template code.

Comment: @AdamDunkerley i did

Comment: Where is ```drugCostTable``` in your template?

Comment: @AdamDunkerley I further transform the data  from drugCostTable and assigned variable drugTable to transformed data

Comment: Could you provide a stackblitz with some dummy data instead of your response? It's hard to determine what is wrong with your table from what you have.

Comment: You should be calling `this.ref.markForCheck();` *after* `this.drugCostTable = response;`